# $args[0] not accepting full argument

Tags: powershell

I have a PowerShell script that accepts one argument using `$args[0]`:

```
filepath=args[0]
```

My path to the file is in the temporary folder. When my file path is as given, this will not cause an issue:

```
C:\Users\tommy.tom\AppData\Local\Temp\setup\File1.exe
```

But when my file path is as given below:

```
C:\Users\$test~1\AppData\Local\Temp\setup\File2.exe
```

`$test` in the path become `$null` and path become:

```
C:\Users\~1\AppData\Local\Temp\setup\File2.exe
```

How can I pass the value correctly to script?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To add to Naigel answer.  When placing in double quotes you and you want to use variables in your path as well.  You would have to escape $ using the back tick "`".  This would indicate to powershell not treat it as a variable.

So alternatively you could write

```
$subDir = "AppData"
.\myScript.ps1 "aa`$atest\$moreDir"
```

And this would effectively pass: aa$atest\AppData

Answer (score 3):

`$test` is considered by powershell as a variable, probably it's tring to resolve it.
Maybe the problem is how you call your script.

For example if you call it like this `.\myScript.ps1 "aa$atest"` the `args[0]` var will contain `aa`, while if you call `.\myScript.ps1 'aa$atest'` the  `args[0]` var will contain `aa$test` because content of single quotes won't be expanded